# after replacing micro usb port, tablet charges only 450mah

Tags: usb, battery-charging, usb-device, usb-host

I changed micro usb port which was broken (it takes out from motherboard) on tablet. On motherboard are 5 contacts and one is damaged (4. - it is for data transfer, ID). I solder +5 VDC contact and Ground, and left 4,3,2 pins for data transfer (not solder them). Now tablet is charging but "only" with 450mA. Why charging chip doesnt increase charging power more than 450mah. I think that 4,3,2 pins are not needed for charging by charger, only for data transfer and smart recognition. Am I right or wrong?

[image: USB pinout]

Comment: how much is 450mAh in mA?

Comment: I've chosen this as a duplicate because the linked question answers this as well. D+ and D- are usually needed to let the device know what kind of current is available.

Comment: So if I solder D+ and D- which are ok, will it charges optimaly? I have damaged ID pin (4), will it affect on some way for charging?

Comment: @Infinity001 I don't think the ID pin is important for charging. It is unconnected in the linked question as well.

Comment: You'd only need the ID pin if you want to function as a USB host using one of those adapter cables.

Comment: You are wrong that D+/D- are not needed. Search SE EE for "charger signature" topics.

Comment: Thx on answers to all, will solder D+/D- and try to solder ID also